# How to jump all dialog BOX by code?

Tags: dialog, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Is there a way to jump all *Dialog Box* in standard code?

For example if in `TaxVatTable.validateWrite` call a class `TaxVATNumValidateES\validateVATNum` and here exist a BOX and I don't want to show, is there a solution?

Exist a way to disable dialog box function in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just modify the relevant methods in `\Classes\Box`.

The issue is those `Box` messages are a **decision** point being made by the user. So how do you know what they'll always choose? You can return the `_defaultButton` and probably be O-K in most cases.

They call different types of forms, but the one you're referring to is `\System Documentation\Classes\DialogBox` which is kernel code so the lowest point you can override it is at the `Box` class.

You can see how they short-circuit by doing this:

```
if (clientKind() == ClientType::COMObject)
    return _defaultButton;
```

**EDIT:**

I want to add that I do NOT recommend doing this. Just change the code in the locations where it's called. You'd be functionally breaking part of the framework. Other developers may NEED to call this functionality at some point.

It's used on forms and all over the place. If you just make it always return `Yes`, you could cause ALL sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny, It's very boring, but I have to find all point where there is a DialogBox

Comment: Use the cross reference and it will take seconds to find. You can build it by following this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa877386.aspx . Then you can just right click on `DialogBox` under `SystemDocumentation` or the `Box` class and say `AddIns>Where Used` and it will identify every place they're used.